# Java, prevent class from calling a public method

Tags: java, exception, public

For an assignment I have to write code for a "State" class that has all the attributes about position of an airplane.

The Javadoc is already written up and must be strictly adhered to. All the set methods are public but must throw an exception if any class other than Airplane try to use them.

I can't change the structure of either class at all or the visibility. My professor said to use either a "clone" or a boolean somehow. How would I go about doing this?

```
public void setSpeed(double speed)
{
    if(method called by any class other than Airplane.java)
    {
        //throw exception
    }
    else
    {
        //continue setting speed
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show an [mcve]

Comment: Frankly, the assignment doesn't seem to make much sense. This is something you don't want to be doing in production code.

Comment: is the `State` method an `Airplane` innerclass?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this requirement is nonsense but this could do it:

```
public void setSpeed(double speed)
{
   if(!Airplane.class.equals(Thread.getCurrentThread().getStacktrace()[1].getClass()))
   {
    //throw exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are non-static methods, we can use `getClass()` to check who called the method and compare it with the `Airplane.class`.  The getStackTrace() technique is great, but not needed here.  Also we should use `!=` instead of `equals(Object)` because we want to check the actual class and not allow a situation where the implementation of `Airplane.equals(Object)` does not check sub-classes.

```
public void something() {
    if (Airplane.class != getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot call from " + getClass());
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. This only fails, if the object is a subclass of `Airpane`. Furthermore whether an exception is thrown is completely independent from the calling class. E.g. `new Airpane().something()` doesn't throw an exception no matter where it's called.

Comment: Ah good point.  I'll have to think a bit more.